# How can i make a verification button on discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been playing around with making a verification button on discord, whenever i press the "Verify" button it gives me the error "This Interaction Failed"

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=discord.Intents.all(), help_command=None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online!")

@bot.command()
async def verify(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Click the button below to verify yourself')

    def check_author(interaction):
        return interaction.user.id == ctx.author.id

    verify_button = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, label='Verify')

    view = discord.ui.View()
    view.add_item(verify_button)

    message = await ctx.send(view=view)

    try:
        interaction = await bot.wait_for('button_click', timeout=30.0, check=check_author)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.edit(content='Verification timed out', view=None)
    else:
        member = ctx.author
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Verified')
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content='You have been verified!', view=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to work with user interactions in `discord.py` is to create views from classes that inherit `discord.ui.View`. Here's how you could build your view:

```py
class VerificationView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        super().__init__(timeout=30)
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.message = None

    async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> bool:
        return interaction.user == self.ctx.author

    async def start(self):
        self.message = await self.ctx.send(content='Click the button below to verify yourself', view=self)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Verify", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def verify(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.Button):
        member = interaction.user
        role = discord.utils.get(self.ctx.guild.roles, name='Verified')
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content='You have been verified!', view=None)

    async def on_timeout(self):
        await self.message.edit(content='Verification timed out', view=None)
```

With the view prepared, all you need to do is use the `start()` method in your command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def verify(ctx: commands.Context):
    view = VerificationView(ctx)
    await view.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't created a discord bot on python before but instead created using a C# library but I think the fix is similar when it comes to interaction module.

For me what solved this issue was calling defer function within the callback function that gets called when the button is pressed. I assume you are using discord.py. I found the name of the function is identical.

Discord.py -  [defer](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.defer)

What this function does is that it acknowledges the interaction and allows you to do time consuming tasks, perhaps, call database or wait for response from an external API.